# Expand Hidden Row within a Range

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm a complete beginner with coding.  I've put together a Hidden Sub Worksheet to hide rows within a list of qualification questions.  As Column A drop downs are selected certain rows need to be manipulated to hide/un-hide. I have attempted to have a rows with a predefined range to be manipulated however to avail.  I've attempted to use the Record Macro function creating a sub Macro that also does not work.  How do I make individual rows withing a predefined range hide/un-hide?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        If Range("A1").Value = "Retail" Then
            Rows("1:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("20:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("12:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Restaurant" Then
            Rows("20:69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("1:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Hospitality" Then
            Rows("20:69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("1:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Professional Service" Then
            Rows("20:69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("1:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Event" Then
            Rows("20:69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("1:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Mail/Telephone" Then
            Rows("20:69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("1:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Internet" Then
            Rows("1:69").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("20:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Nonprofit" Then
            Rows("20:69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("1:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("A9").Value = "No" Then
            Call Macro3
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Rows("11:18").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: right now I don't really get what you want... depending on the value in A1 you want to hide/unhide rows... so what do you need to know?

Comment: You can only hide or unhide an entire row, not part of a row, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to works fine, but can be reduced:

---

For example:

```
Rows("20:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("12:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Range `Rows("70:70")` is a Part of Range `Rows("20:70")`, so the part of code  `Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True` can be removed.

---

another example is:

```
        Rows("20:69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("1:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False  
        Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

`Rows("70:70")` and `Rows("20:69")` can be merged, so can be `Rows("20:70")` instead of `Rows("20:69")` and this part of code `Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True` can be removed.

---

*also*:

- it is not required to use `.EntireRow` when you work with `Rows`, is enough use `Rows("20:69").Hidden = True`
- You can use multiple range: 
  `Range("12:17","70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True` 
  instead of code below:
  `Rows("12:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True`
  `Rows("70:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True`

so, with all that was described above and with using shorthand method of referencing Ranges, your code can looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        If [A1].Value = "Retail" Then
           [1:11].EntireRow.Hidden = 0
           [12:17,20:70].EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        ElseIf [A1].Value = "Restaurant" Then
            [1:19].EntireRow.Hidden = 0
            [20:70].EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        ElseIf [A1].Value = "Hospitality" Then
            [1:19].EntireRow.Hidden = 0
            [20:70].EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        ElseIf [A1].Value = "Professional Service" Then
            [1:20].EntireRow.Hidden = 0
            [20:70].EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        ElseIf [A1].Value = "Event" Then
            [1:19].EntireRow.Hidden = 0
            [20:70].EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        ElseIf [A1].Value = "Mail/Telephone" Then
            [1:19,70:70].EntireRow.Hidden = 0
            [20:69].EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        ElseIf [A1].Value = "Internet" Then
            [1:69].EntireRow.Hidden = 0
            [20:20].EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        ElseIf [A1].Value = "Nonprofit" Then
            [1:19].EntireRow.Hidden = 0
            [20:70].EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        ElseIf [A9].Value = "No" Then
            [11:18].EntireRow.Hidden = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```